# Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR returns null

Tags: android, android-sensors

When I call SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)on my device it returns null. I know this is a virtual sensor (doing some clever maths to take values from real sensors). I it returns null because my device does not have one of the hardware sensors needed for the ROTATION_VECTOR to work.

So my questions are:

- what hardware sensors are required to make the ROTATION_VECTOR work
- what physical devices do this (i.e. if I was buying a tablet today and wanted rotation vector sensor to work, what deveice would I need to buy)?
- what options do I have to work out the devices orientation without the ROTATION_VECTOR sensor?

Edit: We spoke to Samsung about this and decided that the gyro sensor in the tablet was broken and that was why we were getting null back as the rotation_vector sensor.

Comment: On my Galaxy Tab 2 the rotation vector sensor is null, which is very strange as this sensor is virtual. In other words it is software-derived from the physical accelerometer and magnetometer sensors and they exist! I have a custom 4.2.2 ROM installed. I'm curious if that is the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read documentation about [how coordinates are defined](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) for this sensor (find section `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:`), then required hardware is obvious: `accelerometer` and `magnetometer`. Gyroscope also may be used to get more stable result (I've got somewhere link with description how this sensor work but can't find it).

Comment: would appreciate it if you could find your link on how the sensors work. Thanks

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k search for: android sensor fusion (this is how TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR works).

Comment: Very useful. Thanks. Edited question as discovered the gyro was missing from this device.

Comment: To be precise Gyroscope is expressly required here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html *The improved sensors rely on the gyroscope sensor to improve their output, so the sensors appeemphasized textar only on devices that have a gyroscope*.